# Does the html5 <audio> tag load the audio from the server before activating?

Tags: jquery, html

I didn't quite know how to phrase the question, but here is the code...

```
<audio class='foo' preload='none'>
    <source src='./path.mp3'>
</audio>
```

I then have some jQuery that plays the clip when clicked with this function...

```
function play(parent, child) {
    $(parent).find(child).find('.bar').click(function() {
        $('.word-audio')[0].play();
    });
}
```

My question is whether this transfers the audio file when the html loads or when the button is clicked? I would like to only be loading data when buttons are clicked since my page could possibly have hundreds of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not preloading the audio. This behavior is because you are using the `preload="none"` attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio. This behavior is part of the W3 standard, not just Firefox; see https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio.

Answer (score 3):

I think this description will clear your douts...

```
<audio preload="auto|metadata|none">
```

**Attribute Values**

**auto** :  The author thinks that the browser should load the entire audio file when the page loads 
**metadata** :  The author thinks that the browser should load only metadata when the page loads
**none** :  The author thinks that the browser should NOT load the audio file when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

YES. You need to setup preload none if you whant to stop load BUT there is one problem:

> When someone click on audio and stop him, play another and stop in
>   middle of listen, all stopped audio's will continue to load in
>   background.

Only way to stop that is to all audio links load via PHP and iframe.

In one PHP you need to setup audio player. On your page where you display audio lists you need to display only some image and title and when someone click on audio, you need to send ID of your audio to PHP where is audio player and load on page like iframe.

After when someone stop audio, you need to stop audio and destroy iframe.